The solution of an elliptic system vanishes wherever force term vanishes
Let $B(x)$ be a smooth and strongly elliptic forth-order tensor with $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, that is, there exists $c > 0$ such that $B a  a \ge c \Vert a \Vert^2$ for any matrix $a \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$. Suppose $-\nabla \cdot (B(x) \nabla u) = f$ in $B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $u \in H_0^1(B(0,1),\mathbb{R}^3)$. Assume that $f \in C_c^{\infty}(B(0,1/2),\mathbb{R}^3)$. Is it true that $u = 0$ on $B(0,1)\setminus B(1,1/2)$? It seems to me that by using the Green's function, the result is correct. Is there any proof of this statement by weak/variational formulation? Or is the statement incorrect?

What are your assumptions on $B$? For example if $B\equiv 0\equiv f$, then $u$ can be anything.

@SeverinSchraven Thank you for pointing this out. I mentioned in the title but forgot to add to the question that $B(x)$ is strongly elliptic.
